# Remove all empty folders in a subfolder using a batchfile?

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that will delete all files older than 31 days from a nested file structure.

At some point, it will leave empty folders in place, and I'm looking for a way to delete them, ideally keep folders that are newer than 31 days. Given that `rd FolderName` will not remove a folder if its not empty, I can use this to delete folders. The problem is, if I do this, it will not remove all empty folders, only the one that is deepest in the tree. If I could reverse the list forfiles gives me, it would work. If that's not possible, is there another way?

NB: rd /s will not just remove folders nested, but will also remove its files. I don't want to remove the folder if its not empty.

Here's my script:

```bat
@echo off
cd /d "C:\MyPath"

:: remove files that are older than 31 days (retention period)
forfiles /s /d -31 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del @relpath")

:: attempt to remove folders (will fail if the folder is not empty.)
forfiles /s /d -31 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rd @relpath"
```

The above script will only remove the deepest folder. I suppose I could execute forfiles 8 times in a row, but that's a serious waste of resources.

Comment: `SORT` has a `/r` option...

Comment: @Magoo interesting. Now I have to figure out how to make that work with my script. forfiles | sort /r works, but how do I execute a command with it? If you have the answer, feel free to write me an answer and I'll gladly award you with a vote and check. :)

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s/b/ad "C:\mypath" ^|sort /r') do echo %%a` would produce a basic directory list within subdirectories of directories, then sort it in reverse so that any directoryname appears *after* its subdirectories in the list.

Comment: @Magoo thanks for your help. While you posted your comments, I found a similar approach. :) In my case, I can utilize forfiles' option to exclode folders newer than 31 days which is prefered in my case.

Answer (score 1):

For the removal of the no content directories the following, as already implied by @Magoo would be better and much faster than your own answer:

```bat
FOR /F "DELIMS=|" %%A IN ('DIR/B/S/AD-S-L^|SORT/R') DO RD "%%A" 2>NUL
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is faster? Also, it would not exclude folders that are empty but newer than 31 days.

Comment: I just noticed my question didn't specify that I'd like to keep empty folders within 31 days if possible. I'll edit that in. But if the performance is very different I may choose to ignore the 31 days.

Comment: Your question did not stipulate that you wish to keep empty directories in the tree for up to 31 days! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46033592/edit) your question accordingly then accept your own answer as the solution.

Comment: Lets forget the 31 days thingy for a second. Can you explain why yours is faster if I ignore the 31 day retention period? If the gain is much faster, your answer obviously is better.

Comment: For every single forfiles match a separate instance of cmd.exe is being run, you are also running those within a for loop which also effectively runs within a separate cmd.exe instance. The larger your tree the greater the time difference.

Comment: I see. The tree is going to be very small because in theory it would not find folders most of the time because everything older than 31 days is automatically removed, and I check for folder age, so it does not start a single process if forfiles does not yield any result. I hear what you're saying, but in my case it seems my way is actually optimal. +1 for the explaination though. :)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46033592/edit) your question to match your solution then accept your own answer as that solution.

Comment: Already edited it, but I cannot accept my solution just yet. Need to wait 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

With help from @Magoo, who pointed out I can use sort /r to reverse a list, I managed to get to a solution.

The code used is as follows:

```bat
@echo off
cd /d "C:\MyPath"

:: remove files that are older than 31 days (retention period)
forfiles /s /d -31 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del @relpath")

:: attempt to remove folders (will fail if the folder is not empty.)
for /f %%i IN ('forfiles /s /d -31 /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE echo @relpath" ^|sort /r') DO rd %%i
```

Comment: Your answer does not meet your own question criteria, it only removes directories were have not been modified in the last 30 days and have no content. You wanted to delete all files which have not been modified in the last 30 days then remove all directories of any age which have no content.

Comment: @compo The row added in my answer is the last line of my script. I could copy the text of the script in my answer, but it seemed overkill. But if it makes you happy I'll edit the script to add it.